# How to recalculate the total of column's values after removing a row from table

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to recalculate the total of values of 3rd column of a table. Here i am adding rows on Add button. Rows are added with the remove button in a table. I want to recalculate values of 3rd column after clicking remove button which removes the row. But here total does not change after removing row

On stackOverflow i have found the solutions but no answer met my requirements

```
   //To recalculate after deleting
        function reCalculate() {
            var total = 0;
            var value=0;
            $("#Quantity").each(function () {
                debugger;
                value = $(this).text();
                // add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                    total += parseInt(value);
                }
            });
            alert(total);
        }

          //To remove the row from the table
        function RemoveRow(button) {
                var row = $(button).closest("TR");
                var table = $("#table")[0];
                table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
                reCalculate();

            }
```

Expected result is to recalculate all the values in the column properly but it is giving the total is 0

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="orderContainer">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th class="hidden"></th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Extended Amount</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="enterOrder">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, Model.ProductsList, "Select Item", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProductList", required = "required" })
                        <span class="error" id="errorForDropDown" style="color:red; display:none">This field is required</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden" id="ProductIdd"></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input id="UnitPrice" style="width:80px;" name="UnitPrice" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input id="Quantity" style="width:80px;" name="Quantity" type="number" class="form-control" oninput="CalculateExtendedAmount()" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input id="ExtendedAmount" style="width:80px;" name="ExtendedAmount" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="button" value="Add" id="addOrderRow" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddRow()" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <h3>Total</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:300px; border-width:medium; border-color:darkcyan">
                <tr>
                    <td>Total Items/Quantities</td>
                    <td><span id="TotalQuantity"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Order Total</td>
                    <td>$ <span id="TotalOrder"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button id="submitOrder" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="SubmitOrder()" disabled="disabled">Submit Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML. There are 2 tables. One is showing the adding rows on Add button and other is just to show the total of quantity and extendedAmount

Comment: Please include your HTML, without it it's very hard to find the problem.

Comment: Could you please show us some HTML.

Comment: Just a note, the `id` attribute's value must always be unique. And from the looks of `$("#Quantity").each`, it seems that you have multiple input with the same id

Comment: I have added Html

Comment: convert `id="Quantity"` to `class="Quantity"` for each `Quantity <td>` and then change `$("#Quantity")` to `$(".Quantity")`. As multiple element cannot have same `id`. It's invalid HTML as well as you can't use it in jquery as well

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie  $(".Quantity").each(function () { } like that? I have tried this but it is not working

Comment: a)Multiple HTML element with same `id` is actually an invalid Markup.b)`id` is treated as unique identifier in jQuery (single element having that id in entire HTML loaded) c)`class` is treated as group identifier in jQuery(to represent multiple element of same kind) So convert:`<td><input id="Quantity" ..../></td>` To:`<td><input class="Quantity" .../></td>` In each row And then convert `$("#Quantity")` to `$(".Quantity")` And `value = $(this).text();` to `value = $(this).val();` in your jQuery code.

Comment: Thankyou so much i did in this way it is working properly (y)